# In C#, Parse string into individual characters

Tags: c#, string, parsing, character

In C#, how do you parse a string into individual characters?
Given:
    word = “Wonderful”;

Desired Result:
    letter[0] = ‘W’;
    letter[1] = ‘o’;
    letter[2] = ‘n’;
    letter[3] = ‘d’;
    letter[4] = ‘e’;
    letter[5] = ‘r’;
    letter[6] = ‘f’;
    letter[7] = ‘u’;
    letter[8] = ‘l’;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Char[] letters = word.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: This works, but I am using @chemicalNova as the accepted answer because there are less steps.  I do appreciate your answer! I added a point to your useful points.

Comment: @James it's a QA site so all knowledge is valuable, even the simplistic things

Comment: @CN you stated you wanted a character array, his you have to set each one invidually, not sure how it's easier

Comment: @msarchet Going through my program.  I found out that it was optimal for me to use your character array.  I made your answer the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Strings actually have an indexer method for that ...

```
string word = "Wonderful";
char letter1 = word[0]; // W
char letter2 = word[1]; // o
char letter3 = word[2]; // n
```

etc..

Comment: I used your answer as the accepted answer, because it has the least amount of steps.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do anything at all. You can just access the characters by index from the string.

Given:

```
string word = "Wonderful";
```

You have:

```
word[0] = 'W'
word[1] = 'o'
word[2] = 'n'
word[3] = 'd'
word[4] = 'e'
word[5] = 'r'
word[6] = 'f'
word[7] = 'u'
word[8] = 'l'
```