# Error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

Tags: c#, string, error-handling, char, equals

I am getting the error below, and I don't know how to fix it. I just want to learn but cant figure this one out. I tried to replace it with an equal (`=`) and with lots of things but no use, the code is:

```
if (keyinfo.KeyChar == "a") 
{

}
```

This is the error:

> 0019  Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'

How can I avoid getting this error?

Comment: if (keyinfo.KeyChar == 'a')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator ‘==’ cannot be applied to operands of type ‘char’ and ‘string’](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19205107/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-char-and-string)

Comment: *Can't find mistake* and *can't figure this out* are not meaningful problem descriptions. Please [edit] your question. Your title should explain the problem you're having or question you're asking with meaningful content that will be useful to others in the future who see it in a search result. You should also provide a clear description of the problem and ask a  **specific question** about that problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `'a'` and not `"a"`, the difference between `char` and `string` is subtle here but substantial.